# Run external javascript code dynamically as a part of the script

Tags: javascript, eval

I need to execute some javascript code from a string as a part of the current script.
I tried to do it with eval, but for example there is a problem with classes declaration

```
let code = "class A { test() {console.log('A class');} }; new A().test();";
eval(code);
new A().test();
```

In this example the A class will be instantiated successfully in the code from the `code` variable. But the next line execution will fail with

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined
```

I need to do it like clear code injection from **client side** script (i.e. I can't use string formatting on the server-side for example).

Is there a method for it? Or is there an error in my eval usage?

I want to have a code like

```
// Do something
executeScript(getScriptFromUrl("scipr url here"));
let obj = new ClassFromScript();
obj.doSomething();
```

Comment: _"I need to execute some javascript code from a string as a part of the current script."_ - **why?**

Comment: `executeScript(getScriptFromUrl("scipr url here"));`  <-- This won't work in a browser because anything involving making HTTP requests to load something (such as another script, whether for a new `HTMLScriptElement` or even the dreaded `eval` will be asynchronous.

Comment: if i understand you correctly. I can make a synchronous HTTP request here with XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Only in certain situations, and that's only because of back-compat. It wouldn't surprise me if browser makers remove that ability eventually.